# How to convert/export SQL Server database to MSAccess from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL Server database, i need to export all of the data into an Access mdb that users can download. What's the simplest way of doing this from C#?

I realise I could have a blank (but with schema in place) mdb, and when i want to export I could copy it, then read all the data from SQL Server into the mdb via datasets, but that seems like a right faff. Is there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the 'Import/Export' feature in SQL Management Studio to create the Access database when needed? Much easier than writing your own code.

Comment: because the user needs to action it, although i may suggest this as an option

Comment: is there a way to automate/expose that feature somehow so it doesnt need to be a manual task?

Comment: It is possible to create an mdb or accdb with ADOX, if that is any help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you create a DTS Package to do the export, then write a C# app to execute the DTS package, the user then just needs to execute your C# app? You could also set the DTS package to run automatically if you don't want user interaction.