# Convert Access 2010 to SQL 2008

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sqldataadapter

just writing a tool (c# .Net 4) to convert an existing Access 2010 database to SQL Server 2008.
At the moment i have to convert the data types and build the "create" commands for table and the constraints manually.

So whats the fastest way to get the schema from Access with the DataAdapter and create a table from the DataTable at the SQL Server with all the constratins and converted typs ?

```
              OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(accCmd);
              DataTable accSchema = new DataTable();
              da.FillSchema(accSchema, SchemaType.Source);
              //now create db table at sql server from accSchema
```

Thanks for your help.
Gpx

Comment: Can't you use SSIS to do this sort of thing for you?

Comment: There is a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071044/how-to-convert-export-sql-server-database-to-msaccess-from-c and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559394/ms-access-application-convert-data-storage-from-access-to-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this in the past when upsizing my access applications and it did a good job

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access v5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, tried the tool, ended the conversion with "An unexpected error occurred." and no further info. It did some work though but i´m note quite sure if it did everything right.

Comment: One of the things I think is a UI design error in the SSMA is that the wizard that starts up does the actual conversion, instead of allowing you to test it first and then fix anything that doesn't work. I found that dismissing the wizard and doing it manually is more useful, as you can see exactly what won't convert the way you want it and then adjust your source database to fix it (assuming there's a fix available).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't use an existing tool? Saves re-inventing the wheel.

http://projects.c3o.com/files/3/plugins/entry11.aspx

http://dbcopytool.codeplex.com/

Comment: I can't tell with the first one but the second one looks like it's SQL Server to SQL Server only

Comment: Sure not trying to re-invent, but building one tool for different initial databases and not searching the web for couple of converters. So is it possible anyhow?